# How to delete a combobox's selected item from another Combobox

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create a simple ticket fair app but I'm stuck at some place.
I have load-Data() method which populates the 2 combo box (destination & source), each contains the same list of cities. I want Destination's selected item(city) removed from the Source.

I disabled the source combo box which gets enabled from the Selection_Changed event of Destination combo box.

I tried removing selected item of Destination from source at Selection_Changed event. but then it occurred to me what if user selects wrong item in the first place? it will get removed from the source anyway.

Any advice how do I go about achieving this?

here's the code i tried:

```
private void DestinationCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // await LoadData();
        object selectedItem = DestinationCombo.SelectedItem;
            if(SourceCombo.Items.Contains(selectedItem))
            {
                SourceCombo.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
            }

        //await LoadData();
        SourceCombo.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

'LoadDate' Method:

```
private async Task LoadData()
        {
            DestinationCombo.Items.Clear();
            SourceCombo.Items.Clear();
            file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("jsonText.txt");
            var jsonContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            DataModel2.RootObject states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel2.RootObject>(jsonContent);

            foreach (var state in states.country.state)
            {
                foreach (var city in state.city)
                {

                    DestinationCombo.Items.Add(city);
                    SourceCombo.Items.Add(city);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I advice you to post your code/try first

Comment: I've edited my post with code

Comment: can you post the load-data() method?

Comment: Do you need to post back? If you are posting back, then call LoadData each time. If they pick another Destination, you'll reload everything and remove just that one.

Comment: I've posted my loadData() code @FarhanAnam:

Comment: which event i call this method on? @AndyWiesendanger
I tried calling it on pointer_pressed, Selection_changed & many others but fail

Answer (score 3):

First, where all these methods are, i.e., in the class (most likely a Form#), declare a public variable called cities:-

```
public list<string> cities = new list<string>;
```

Then edit your `loaddata()` method a little:

```
private async Task LoadData()
    {
        DestinationCombo.Items.Clear();
        SourceCombo.Items.Clear();
        file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("jsonText.txt");
        var jsonContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

        DataModel2.RootObject states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel2.RootObject>(jsonContent);

        foreach (var state in states.country.state)
        {
            foreach (var city in state.city)
            {
                cities.Add(city);
            }
        }

        DestinationCombo.Items.AddRange(cities.ToArray<String>());
        SourceCombo.Items.AddRange(cities.ToArray<String>());
    }
```

Finally, in the **SourceCombo** `SelectionChanged Event`, put this code:

```
private void SourceCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // await LoadData();
    object selectedItem = SourceCombo.SelectedItem;
    DestinationCombo.Items.Clear();
    DestinationCombo.Items.AddRange(cities.ToArray<String>());
    DestinationCombo.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
    }
```

You can also add similar code to the other ComboBox so that whichever ComboBox (Source or Destination) the user clicks, the selection is removed from the other ComboBox.

Comment: Would not use global or form variable for cities.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming Web. I see Windows store app now.

Comment: @FarhanAnam 
It did not change anything but make it worse, throws this exception {"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"} on "DestinationCombo.Items.Clear();"

Comment: remove that line and see if you get the error or not.

Comment: Same error moved on "DestinationCombo.Items.Remove(selectedItem);"

Comment: Try using `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, listBox1.Items.Clear);`. let me know

Comment: that's strange how come you get an error on such a simple thing (i'm not blaming you)

Comment: fixed it, by making 2 separate methods to populate each combobox. Means 1 to load source and other to load Destination, and i used only LoadDestinationData() at source selectionchanged event(what you suggested). Although its redundant to have 2 almost similar methods. trying to figure out how to reduce it. appreciate your time